# save pdf file in device

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, save

I generated a pdf file in my program and I have it here :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/CEX.pdf"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

I know how to save photos in the photo gallery but have no idea what should I do with pdf file and how and where to save it in the device. Can anyone help me please ?! :)

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is for reading an existing PDF file from the `Documents` directory.

If you want to write the PDF, you need to get the `NSData` object representing the PDF, create a path to the file, then use the `NSData writeToFile:options:error:` method to save the data to the file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDocument.pdf"];

NSData *pdfData = ... // data representing your created PDF
NSError *error = nil;
if ([pdfData writeToFile:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {
    // file saved
} else {
    // error writing file
    NSLog(@"Unable to write PDF to %@. Error: %@", file, error);
}
```

BTW - in your original code, replace:

```
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/CEX.pdf"];
```

with:

```
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CEX.pdf"];
```

Don't use string formats unless you really have a string format to process.